# React instance not being exposed in a browser

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Recently I've been setting up a development stack for React using Webpack (new for me) and of course wanted to benefit from all of the shiny conveniences that it provides (which are by the way great!). Among tons of resources I dug on the internet, the particularly good one I found was the [React Webpack Cookbook](https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook), with which every step went like clockwork. However I stumbled across a hitch that has been taking me several hours to try to solve, not being able to find a solution in the aforementioned page, nor any other source: **the `expose-loader` wouldn't expose `React` to global scope in Chrome (not tested on other browsers) therefore not allowing React DevTools extension to run**. I tried mixing all the steps from the Cookbook, using different versions of React, minified/unprocessed, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was trivial when discovered, but the source of the problem tricky to find: all the time I was using the `localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/` version of my development page, as suggested by the Cookbook, because it allowed me not to bother with the inability to inject `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` into `html-webpack-plugin` index file generator and provided sort of a nice status bar. **It works perfectly since I switched to `localhost:8080`**. Unfortunatelly I wasn't able to make it work with the `localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/` version, though I think it has something to do with the fact that under this url the page is loaded into a frame.

Comment: i am unable to get it to work even after navigating to localhost:8080, do i have to do anything special, this is how my index.html looks like

    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        <h3>this is a test!!!</h3>
        <h3>this is a test!!!</h3>
      </body>
    </html>

Comment: What exactly you can't get working? React instance being exposed in a browser?

Comment: yeah,  it wasn't working then I created a new clone,  started from scratch and it was working!